# Google Cloud Messaging and iOS Bitcode

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging, bitcode

Back in October I had to remove google-cloud-messaging from my iOS app because Apple would not process the App because the google-cloud-messaging library was not compile for Bitcode.  At that time the responses said that Bitcode was going to be enabled in the library in the next release.  Was this ever done?  When was the last release done?  I would like to add google-cloud-messaging back into the app but cannot until Apple will process the app.

Answer (score 0):

> Back in October I had to remove google-cloud-messaging from my iOS app
>   because Apple would not process the App because the
>   google-cloud-messaging library was not compile for Bitcode.

Bitcode is completely optional for iOS apps (it is mandatory for watchOS apps and tvOS apps but not iOS apps), so Apple would not reject an app because it didn't use Bitcode.

Comment: The app wasn't rejected.  The build would not process in the iTunes system during the upload.  When GCM was removed the build processed within 5 minutes.

Comment: I was mainly asking if GCM was updated since the end of September by Google.

Comment: @CChesk: Well it works for everyone else who doesn't have Bitcode. So it must have been a momentary glitch or you are doing something wrong.